# Where is the startup file after blender upgrade to 2.64?

Tags: blender

So, after the upgrade to blender 2.64 my preferences are lost and i have to set it up from the beginning BUT I do not want that. Any ideas of where the blender config file is?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I've managed to find it. The version I'm running is 2.65 but I suspect they started using this since 2.64. Anyway the path to the user pref file is now:

```
/home/USERNAME/.config/blender/2.65/config/userpref.blend
                                      /startup.blend
```

At least, that's the case for me!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you saved the User Settings in Blender, a file called startup.blend is created. It usually resides in

```
~/.blender/[blender version]/config/startup.blend
```

So, for example, if you had saved the settings for version 2.63, it's

```
~/.blender/2.63/config/startup.blend
```

You could copy that file to the config directory of your newly installed version:

```
cp ~/.blender/2.63/config/startup.blend ~/.blender/2.64/config/startup.blend
```

Comment: well thanks but i already know that. My problem is that the settings are not stored in this file any more, so is there are any other possible directory that contains the settings file?Thanks

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.blender/*/config/startup.blend` say? If you have overwritten your settings file by explicitly saving, I'm afraid there's not much you can do.